# nmap - how can I input a target to nmap from a file with the netmask attached?

Tags: network, nmap

I have a c program that gets the router IP and netmask and puts it into a text file in the format of `192.168.1.1/24`. When I issue the nmap scan command with the target text file I get the `unable to split netmask from target expression` error.

This should work... issuing the nmap command with the ip/mask specified rather than reading from file works obviously. Issuing a different nmap command when reading from file with just the ip address in works as well. Only when the /24 is on the end of the address does the error occur.

Is this down to a fundamental flaw in the nmap file reader or is there a way around this?

I am issuing the commands with the popen function in C

```
scan = popen("nmap -sn /tmp/file.txt", "r");
```

Comment: You just want an nmap command string that will handle a network ID?  It sounds like you already have one.  This may be more of a challenge with how you're passing the output to the input of nmap in your coding.  Have you been able to find an example of code that performs this successfully maybe in another language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-iL` argument to nmap to specify the file it is reading, then it will properly expand any CIDR addresses in that file, as shown:

```
$ cat file.txt
192.168.0.1/24
$ nmap -sT -Pn -p 22 -iL file.txt

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-01-09 13:00 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.0
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

...

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.254
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.255
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (256 hosts up) scanned in 63.20 seconds
```

Comment: Do you know if it scans multiple entries async to optimize for time, or would you need a custom implementation for that?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html), `nmap` utilizes parallelism by default.  So it scans multiple entries async, and if you wanted to tweak how async it can get, the command flags to do so are found on that page.